# find the X most frequent number of an N size array

Tags: algorithm, performance

I'm practicing for a coding interview and I found some question the company usally made to new juniors like me in a website and I would like to know if exist a better solution to this one (it's a pseudocode):

"Given an array of N size of integers, find the most X frequents numbers (data array may contain duplicates)"

```
V[N]  = {...} //Data Array
C1[N] = {...} //Count Array (Store the V[k] number)
C2[N] = {...} //Count Array (Store the V[k] number frequency)
M[X]  = {...} //Most Frequent Array

lastFreePositionInC = 0;

//iterate over the data array to count all ocurrence of V[k]
for i=0 to N
  indexOfViInC1 = checkIfViExistInC1(V[i],C1); //This iterates over C1 to find V[i]
  if indexOfViInC1 != -1
    C2[indexOfViInC1]++;
  else //Couldn't find the number, must be added to C
    C1[lastFreePositionInC] = V[i]
    C2[lastFreePositionInC++] = 1

findXMostFrequent(M,X,C1,C2); //You can sort the C array so this is just a merge sort
```

And yes, it's "ilegal" to sort the data array to solve the challenge.

Comment: You don't need to check existence of element in array before incrementing count array. If your array can hold as many element as maximum value in the input array you can initiate a count array with that size and increment like C[V[i]]++, or you can use a map of key->counter

Comment: Your algorithm is O(N^2). Since you have to allocate all that extra space anyway, you should copy the data array and sort the copy for O(log N), or do something like a hash table for expected O(N)

Comment: @Matt Timmermans sadly, it's has to be done using only arrays (so no hash tables, i tried to "simulate" one doing C1 and C2).

Comment: @SomeDude I can't know the maximum value of the array without find it by my self, and if even is it was allowed, it's not memory efficient allocate an array of that size :( (N could be 100 or could be 1000000000).

Comment: You can make a hash table with an array

Comment: Can you please elaborate the restriction? You've mentioned no sorting and no hash tables? Why? If library methods are not allowed, are you allowed to implement your own sorting algorithm or hash table data structure?